# Vuex Return boolean?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to make a function that I can call in my templates called hasPermission with a string. However when I call it, vuex returns a promise object. Is there anyway I can make it return a boolean?

```
hasPermission({ state }, permission) {
  for (var i = 0; i < state.user.permissions.length; i++) {
    var perm = state.user.permissions[i];
    if (perm.name == permission) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

I want to simply be able to call it like v-if="hasPermission("test") and then show based off of the response. However I'm having a bit of a hard time doing this. Would love any advice you can give :)

Comment: You can do `Promise.resolve(true)` and `Promise.reject(false`.
Vuex should not return a promise object though, unless you are trying to read directly from `dispatch` call.

Comment: So would that be return Promise.resolve(true)? Also that function above is in actions.  @UtsavPatel

Comment: If it is an action, then you should `commit` to vuex store and read the value either from `mapState` or `mapGetters`.

Comment: So how would I go about checking if a value is in an array like that? Is there a way to do a function like above with Vuex?

Comment: You are dispatching an action called `hasPermission`, it accepts a parameter called `permission`. 
So you would know whether `permission` is an array or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `hasPermission` a [method-style](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access) getter:

```js
getters: {
  hasPermission: (state) => (permission) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < state.user.permissions.length; i++) {
      var perm = state.user.permissions[i];
      if (perm.name == permission) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Use `mapGetters` to include it in the component:

```js
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
```

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['hasPermission'])
}
```

Use it in the template like:

```html
v-if="hasPermission('test')"
```

Just keep in mind these getters aren't cached like normal getters, but then neither are actions.

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/Lr7ak2wq/)

Comment: I think in OP `hasPermission` is actually an action.

Comment: @UtsavPatel - Yes, it doesn't need to be.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for! Thanks! I'm new to vue and vuex, I think I'm going to need to look into vuex a little more haha.